# Access-Control-Max-Age position in preflight response header?

Tags: http-headers

Where i should put **Access-Control-Max-Age** on preflight response header or xhr response header?

```
Access-Control-Max-Age
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be set on the **OPTIONS PREFLIGHT** request, as it tells the browser for how long it can cache the preflight response data.

> The Access-Control-Max-Age response header indicates how long the
> results of a preflight request (that is the information contained in
> the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers
> headers) can be cached.
> Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age

Comment: I found answer in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/preflight_correct.png